# Inverting a hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I know a clash is possible if you do this. But given a hash of arrays:

```
my %transform = ( 
    'FF0000' => [qw ( error errors assertion )],
    'FFFF00' => [qw ( warning warnings paused )],
    '008000' => [qw ( active )],
);
```

I want to turn this into a search and replace regex.

E.g.

```
my %colour_map = ( 
   'error' => 'FF0000',
   'errors' => 'FF0000',
   'assertion' => 'FFFF00',
   'warning' => 'FFFF00',
   'warnings' => 'FFFF00',
   'paused' => 'FFFF00',
   'active' => '008000',
);

my $search = join( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %colour_map ); 
   $search = qr/\b($search)\b/;
```

So that I can:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my ($match) = m/$search/i ) {
        print "$colour_map{lc($match)} $match\n";
    }
}
```

I'm ok with there being collisions potentially (given arrays don't require uniqueness).

So far I've got:

```
my %colour_map ;
foreach my $colour ( keys %replace ) {
   foreach my $value ( @{$replace{$colour}} ) {
        $colour_map{$value} = $colour;
   }
}
```

I think there *should* be a solution using something like `map` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: How likely are you to add meta characters to a list that reads: "error", "errors", "assertion", "warning", "warnings", "paused", and "active"? Given the trend, and the suggested data-space, I think `quotemeta` is overkill, but there might be shop standards at work here.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't get too preoccupied with *"using something like `map`"* just for the sake of it. If you're having problems devising a solution that works that way then others are likely to have problems understanding what it does when you've managed to cram your foot into the slipper

I believe this is clearest and simplest using a `while` iterator and `each`

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my %transform = (
    'FF0000' => [qw ( error errors assertion )],
    'FFFF00' => [qw ( warning warnings paused )],
    '008000' => [qw ( active )],
);

my %colour_map;

while ( my ($key, $val) = each %transform ) {
    $colour_map{$_} = $key for @$val;
}

dd \%colour_map;
```

#### output

```
{
  active    => "008000",
  assertion => "FF0000",
  error     => "FF0000",
  errors    => "FF0000",
  paused    => "FFFF00",
  warning   => "FFFF00",
  warnings  => "FFFF00",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a double `map` here:

```
my %result = map { 
    my $k = $_;
    map { ( $_ => $k ) } @{$transform{$_}}
} keys %transform;
```

Since we are going to call a `map` within a `map` the context variable has to be saved off to a lexical. However, that is not true with a [**`pairmap`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util#pairmap) from [**`List::Util`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util):

```
use List::Util qw<pairmap>;
...
my %result = pairmap { map { ( $_ => $a ) } @$b } %transform;
```

...because `$a` and `$b` are already set up as local variables.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Can't say that I would recommend doing it this way, but it is possible to do with a single map using a hash slice.

```
my %color_map = (); # merica
map { @color_map{ @{ $transform{ $_ } } } = ($_) x @{ $transform{ $_ } } } keys %transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your original color-keyword mapping using an array reference, instead of an array, as perl will not create the hash you expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %transform = ( 
    'FF0000' => [ qw ( error errors assertion ) ],
    'FFFF00' => [ qw ( warning warnings paused ) ], 
    '008000' => [ qw ( active ) ], 
);

my %color_map = map {
    my ($color) = $_;
    map { $_ => $color } @{ $transform{$color} };
} keys %transform;

print "Original Hash\n";
print Dumper \%transform;
print "Colormap from Hash\n";
print Dumper \%color_map;
```

**Output**

```
Original Hash
$VAR1 = {
      '008000' => [
                    'active'
                  ],
      'FFFF00' => [
                    'warning',
                    'warnings',
                    'paused'
                  ],
      'FF0000' => [
                    'error',
                    'errors',
                    'assertion'
                  ]
    };
Colormap from Hash
$VAR1 = {
      'warnings' => 'FFFF00',
      'assertion' => 'FF0000',
      'errors' => 'FF0000',
      'error' => 'FF0000',
      'warning' => 'FFFF00',
      'active' => '008000',
      'paused' => 'FFFF00'
    };
```